# i want to show data in **only one** textview when i clickd on buttons...both buttons have different data

Tags: android

*firstacivity*

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){    
        case R.id.button :
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
            intent1.putExtra("value1", strsongdetails);
            startActivity(intent1);    
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
            intent2.putExtra("value2", NameOfTheString);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

*secondactivity *

```
TextView textView3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
   textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

//i want to show data in **only one** textview when i clickd on buttons...both buttons have different data
//i create 2 activities In first thereare two buttons and in third there is textview which i wanted to connet a string & when i clickd on button they want to see the data from text view

Comment: Can you rephrase this question to state what you want to achieve? Not clear enough.

Comment: i want to show the data which i take in string field...see for exmple i want show this data in text field  ...      <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Songtrial2</string>
    <string name="strsongdetails">
        ASGHKJFSFFGLIUIEROTI
    </string>
   
    <string name="NameOfTheString">Test stringhskjfhkjshkfjhsdkfh
    dsfsdkfkdsjfkj
    </string>

</resources>

Answer (score 0):

Hello if i have understand your question you want to press a button, send the message to the second activity and display it to a textview. Add this code after textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

```
   String message="";
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("value1")){
        message = getIntent().getStringExtra("value1");
    }else if(getIntent().hasExtra("value2")){
        message = getIntent().getStringExtra("value2");
    }else{
        // no message passed to activity
    }

    textView3.setText(message);
```

Comment: Hello sir,the program is ruuning error free but it cant shows values from the string..